# Highchart lagging in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, highcharts

Hello dear programmers,

i have encountered a performance problem while using highcharts() in firefox browser (firefox quantum 60.0 (64-Bit)). I have a chart with different types of series (area, spline, etc.) where each series may contain several thousand data points (x,y). I reconstructed a chart in jsfiddle (linked below) which simulates my displayed chart.

If i run the jsfiddle in firefox the browser basically shuts down. It lags upon rendering and the display of any tooltips is going slow at best.
If i run the same jsfiddle in google chrome (Version 66.0.3359.139 (64-Bit)) everything works as intended, lag-free.

The time taken to create the charts does not differ much, if any, chrome even takes a little bit longer:
chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Bt0.png
firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnVnu.png

Unfortunately it is not an option to reduce the amount of displayed points or tooltips in the chart, since that is a demanded feature. The chart must work properly in firefox as well. The jsfiddle-code contains the least amount of necessary features to my chart. I'm using the boost module and I already tried to change related parameters such as boostthreshhold, turbothreshhold, useGPUTranslations or usePreAllocated.

English is not my native language. Please excuse any mistakes regarding grammar or vocabulary. And this also is my first post on stackoverflow. I'm sorry if anything is not in accordance with the formatting guidelines.

JSFiddle-Link: https://jsfiddle.net/pjwpujs0/1/

JavaScript Code:

```
function getAreaData(amountOfValues) {
    var arr = [];
    var i;
    // 10 minutes
    var timeinterval = 10 * 60 * 1000;
    // start time: 2016-02-12 10:00:00
    var starttime = 1455271200000;
    var temptime = starttime;
    for (i = 0; i < amountOfValues; i = i + 1) {
         temptime += timeinterval;
         arr.push([
            temptime,
            Math.random() * Math.floor(4000)
         ]);
    }
    return arr;
}

function getLineData(amountOfValues) {
    var arr = [];
    var i;
    // 10 minutes
    var timeinterval = 10 * 60 * 1000;
    // start time: 2016-02-12 10:00:00
    var starttime = 1455271200000;
    var temptime = starttime;
    for (i = 0; i < amountOfValues; i = i + 1) {
        temptime += timeinterval;
        arr.push([
            temptime,
            Math.random() * Math.floor(20)
        ]);
    }
    return arr;
}

var amount = 20000;
var series = [];
series.push({
  name: "Area",
  data: getAreaData(amount),
  lineWidth: 0.5,
  type: 'area',
  tooltip: {
    followPointer: false,
    valueSuffix: 'kW'
  }
});

series.push({
  name: "Line",
  data: getLineData(amount),
  lineWidth: 0.5,
  type: 'spline',
  yAxis: 1,
  tooltip: {
    followPointer: false,
    valueSuffix: 'm/s'
  }
});

console.time('testchart');
this.testChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    boost: {
    allowForce: true,
    enabled: true,
    useGPUTranslations: true,
    debug: {
            showSkipSummary: true,
            timeBufferCopy: true,
            timeKDTree: true,
            timeRendering: true,
            timeSeriesProcessing: true,
            timeSetup: true
    }
  },

  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'area',
    zoomType: 'x'
  },

  title: {
    text: "testchart"
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },

  yAxis: [{
        // primary axis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}kW'
        },
        title: {
            text: "Leistung in [kW]"
        }
    }, { 
        //secondary axis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}m/s' 
        },
        title: {
            text: "Windgeschwindigkeit in [m/s]"
        },
        opposite: true
  }],

  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    valueDecimals: 2
  },

  plotOptions: {
            series: {
                animation: false,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    radius: 1
                }
            }
        },

    series: series
});
console.timeEnd('testchart');
```

Edit1: I just tried to export the graph as svg and received an error:
"*413 Request Entity Too Large*"
maybe this helps

Comment: You could try and turn off all shadows and animations?

Comment: boost.js usually turns off shadows and animations when the boost-feature kicks in. i also implemented it manually, but still same behavior

Comment: Is the jsfiddle you linked the one with the firefox issue? You mentioned that the chart creation is even better in firefox. I opened both and did not have any issues on firefox 60.0 (64 bit). Which OS do you use?

Comment: the mere creation time is slightly better in firefox, yes. (debug info) But i can not work with the chart since it is lagging heavily. And the browser window seems to freeze when the chart is rendered.
Edit: OS: windows 7 professional sp1